# Flex treeview with end nodes which have components

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, treeview, itemrenderer

I am looking about a kind of Treeview ( could be something which fits aswell ) or approach on creating such.

The main idea is as follow : 
on each node, which is end-node ( it is not a parent to anything ) must have a different renderer from the rest of the nodes - a few buttons mostly, arranged vertically.
Which means that these end-nodes shall have different height from the rest aswell..

Comment: this is something bothering me past few days, and i really can't fin a solution, it's like never ending walking into a circle... ... help

Comment: P.S. : I forgot to mention that the end-node shall be expanded vertically, showing more buttons and images. Is it best to leave it in another discussion, or reedit this one ? ( i am not sure how to act properly :| )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough as long as you have hierarchical data (meaning that there's a property of 'children' in each object), you just need to set a custom item renderer which it checks if the data's 'children' property is bigger than 0.

If bigger than zero, change the state within the item renderer to 'node' and if zero, change state to 'leaf'. And make sure you set `variableRowHeight` to true on your Tree.

Comment: Thank you very much, it leads me to some additions developing of the idea, followed by more interesting toughts :)